# Copy data(.csv) from Sql server to Azure Blob Storage(ADLS2) using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy data from Sql to Blob storage using Azure data factory. Although I was able to load the data and creating a trigger for a specific time frame, but not sure how to provide a filename with a timestamp in data factory for every load that occurs weekly. Basically adding a dynamic content where I can mention my file name with date stamped

Can anyone suggest on how to achieve this on data factory?

sample output :  `filename1_29042022.csv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the below code as dynamic content in file name [art of the sink dataset. this returns `filename_20220428.csv`

```
@concat('filename', '_', replace(formatDateTime(convertTimeZone(utcnow(),'UTC','Eastern Standard Time'),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'-',''), '.csv')
```